How to Customized Navigation Drawer in Android
I want to customised my navigation drawer just like shown in image.
In menu item I used layout for that
I want like this
I used this layout but it is shifted to right side.I want to set text and image on left side as shown in image but it is not set properly.After setting below layout to menu`//menu_item_with_badge
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
    android:orientation="horizontal"`
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"`
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_title_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_badge1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:visible="true"
            android:title=""
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_news"
            android:title=""
            android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_with_badge"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_info"
            android:title=""
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_website"
            android:title=""
    
            />
    </group>
    </menu>

